# Gauge symmetries related to kinetic matrix determinant

Tags: quantum-field-theory, symmetry, gauge-theory, action, gauge

Maybe it is a trivial question, but in my books I can not find an explanation why the kinetic matrix determinant gives us information about the gauge symmetries of the theory.

The operator I'm referring to is the one in the quadratic term (e.i. $\frac{1}{2} \phi^i K_{ij} \phi^j$). So if $K_{ij}$ is invertible and thus its determinant non zero, the theory has no gauge symmetry. But why?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

K is usually related to the inverse of the propagator. If we have a propagator we can use it to solve for the field at later times given an initial condition. But in a gauge theory there is not a unique solution unless you fix a gauge.

Or equivalently if K is not invertible, there are some eigenvectors $\delta \phi$ that are annihilated $K\delta\phi=0$. These are just the pure gauge fields.

Comment: ok! I knew the answer involved the propagator but I didn't know how to put pieces together.
So, K is singular unless I fix the gauge (s), did I get it right?
Anyway, thank you :)

Comment: Yep, that's the usual approach. Fix the gauge, K is no longer singular, and then we can define a propagator.